# One way Light switch replacement help

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light, uk

I am trying to replace my current light switch with a new one

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

But getting a bit lost, old one has 2 brown in COM, 1 brown in 1WAY and 3 blue in LOOP do you know how that should map onto my new switch?

My best guess is 3 brown in COM and 3 blue in L1 but honestly, I am very new and have no idea!

Comment: This is UK yep.

Comment: Think you have to keep the two brown(hot?) together and the single brown(switch hot?) separate if you want the light to go off and on by the switch.  Do nothing until you find out from someone with knowledge of UK power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure your empty connection in the old switch says either 2-way or L2, to make sure we have a standard 2-way switch used as a one-way<sup>[1]</sup>, plus a loop junction.

In essence there's only one active switched pair in there, the others enable onward/backward connectivity. *Don't mix & match* as you move these, each 'set' goes from one old hole to one new hole...

Move your two `Com` wires to `Com`, move `1 Way` to `L1`, leave `L2` empty & join your loop wires into a spare piece of terminal block, going nowhere except each other. Tape the block up  & leave loose in the box.

Make sure you correctly connect all your earths too - your old switch isn't earthed because it's all-plastic. Your new switch has an earth tab because the patress screw surrounds are metal.
Don't skip it.
One new wire from the Earth tab in the switch to the back-box earth terminal, along with all other earths.

<sup>[1]</sup> It is quite common for 2-way switches to be used in one-way wiring. The difference in cost is minimal, so having one box of switches that can be used as either type is easy to manage. Then you only need 'specials' if you're wiring two ways with intermediates.